# Citadel outputting 'Broadcase message from systemd-journald@hostname' continuously

Tags: systemd, journald, ubuntu-15.10, citadel

I installed citadel-suite using apt-get on Ubuntu 15.10.  I then uninstalled it using 'sudo apt-get remove citadel-suite; sudo apt-get purge citadel-suite', manually deleted the directory '/etc/citadel/', and then re-installed it using apt-get.  I thought it would re-run the easy install, but alas no.  After reading the Citadel's [FAQs](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/doku.php?id=faq:start) and [docs](http://www.citadel.org/doku.php/doku.php?id=documentation:start), I ran Citadel's 'setup' executable.  Now it's totally borked.  It's spitting out messages like the following as fast as it can go:

Broadcast message from systemd-journald@hostname (Thu 2016-07-14 21:09:52 PDT):
citserver[12510]: failed to create directory /etc/citadel/messages/: No such file or directory
Broadcast message from systemd-journald@hostname (Thu 2016-07-14 21:09:52 PDT):
citserver[12510]: failed to access & create directories
Broadcast message from systemd-journald@hostname (Thu 2016-07-14 21:09:52 PDT):
citserver[12511]: configuration setting c_default_cal_zone is empty, but must not - check your config!
Broadcast message from systemd-journald@hostname (Thu 2016-07-14 21:09:52 PDT):
citserver[12511]: failed to create directory /etc/citadel/messages/: No such file or directory
Broadcast message from systemd-journald@hostname (Thu 2016-07-14 21:09:52 PDT):
citserver[12511]: failed to access & create directories

I then rebooted the server, but it's still spitting out the same messages from systemd-journald.  Anyone have any ideas on how to fix it and get Citadel re-installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `/etc/citadel` directory by hand (`mkdir /etc/citadel`).  Obviously citadel's too poorly implemented to know about `mkdir -p`.  Bodes well for future operations.